# Getting Invalid use of group function for lengthy MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to get this query together but right when I thought I was done and tried running it, I get that error. I'm pretty sure it is about the line:

**-> AND SUM(cr.file_size) > 5000000000**

```
   SELECT ss.TITLE
        -> ,SUM(cr.file_size)
        -> ,gr.user_id
        -> ,ru.givenname
        -> ,ru.sn
        -> ,ru.mail
        -> FROM CONTENT_RESOURCE cr
        -> ,SAKAI_SITE ss
        -> ,SAKAI_REALM_RL_GR gr
        -> ,SAKAI_REALM rl
        -> ,rutgers_user ru
        -> ,SAKAI_USER_ID_MAP map
        -> WHERE cr.CONTEXT = ss.SITE_ID
        -> AND SUM(cr.file_size) > 5000000000
        -> AND rl.realm_id = CONCAT ('/site/',ss.site_id)
        -> AND rl.realm_key = gr.realm_key
        -> AND gr.role_key IN (7,3)
        -> AND gr.user_id = map.user_id
        -> AND map.eid = ru.uid
        -> INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/siteContentUsage.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: you don't have group by clause

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YpcwlOs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `having` clause.  Aggregation functions don't belong in `where` clauses:

```
HAVING SUM(cr.file_size) > 5000000000
```

Of course, this presupposes that you have a `group by` clause as well, because the `having` clause should go after the `group by`.  I'm not sure what that is, perhaps `group by user_id`.

Also, you should learn proper explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I'd much rather have something work the right way then just work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for that I'm probably going to read up on it later

Comment: If your comment is about the `join` syntax, it is because explicit joins are more powerful than implicit joins, because they readily support outer joins.  (I also find them much easier to read, but given the more powerful functionality, aesthetics is a secondary consideration.)